# How to make robot or Dalek voice using SoX library?

Tags: audio, voice, sox, synthesizer

I want to transform my voice into robot voice( ex : goliath voice of starcraft game) using SoX library.

I found the following sequence for robot voice on the web,
but it doesn't make robot voice.

Overdrive 10
echo 0.8 0.8 5 0.7
echo 0.8 0.7 6 0.7
echo 0.8 0.7 10 0.7
echo 0.8 0.7 12 0.7
echo 0.8 0.88 12 0.7
echo 0.8 0.88 30 0.7
echo 0.6 0.6 60 0.7

What effects are needed to make robot voice?
Could you tell me a sequence of effects and options?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From a robotics researcher's point of view: If you want a _realistic_ robot voice, just use any text-to-speech synthesis software, this is what we do on real robots. (But I guess, this is not, what you want, therefore just a comment)

Comment: I think the OP wants a way to transform its own voice into some kind of robotic voice whether it be on the fly or for recorder  clips for the seek of privacy. Using what you @luator suggest would be just a work aroung, but wouldn't do the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. But what I want is transform from voice recorded audio file to robot voice audio file using SoX library :-)

Answer (score 5):

To implement the settings the OP had found, all you need to do is to type thusly:

```
play INPUTFILE overdrive 10 echo 0.8 0.8 5 0.7 \
echo 0.8 0.7 6 0.7 echo 0.8 0.7 10 0.7 echo 0.8 0.7 12 0.7 \
echo 0.8 0.88 12 0.7 echo 0.8 0.88 30 0.7 echo 0.6 0.6 60 0.7
```

I don't know anything about Star Trek, so I can't say if it fits the bill in that regard, but it produces a thin metallic, clearly alien voice.

I also played around a bit trying to recreate the Dalek voice (yes I know, not really robots, but what a voice!). As luator noted, for a properly robotic sound you'd use some text-to-speech software, so I implemented that as well:

```
say -v Albert -o exterminate.aiff --data-format=BEI16@44100 \
exterminate, exterminate, exterminate!

play exterminate.aiff stretch 1.2 133.33 lin 0.2 0.4 \
overdrive 30 30 echo 0.4 0.8 15 0.8 \
synth sine fmod 30 echo 0.8 0.8 29 0.8
```

The `say` command will of course only work in OSX, but there might be other, and hopefully better solution out there. All the Apple voices have a pretty heavy american accent, it just doesn't sound right when coming from a Dalek.

The `stretch` option is purposely badly implemented, especially the window length of 133ms has a really good effect. `Overdrive` gives a lot of nice non-linear distortion. I [read](http://www.homebrewaudio.com/doctor-dalek-voice/) that in reality the Dalek voice is created by the use of a Moogerfooger ring modulator using a 30Hz carrier tone, and that's essentially what I've done with the `synth sine fmod 30` option. On top of that a few moderately short echoes has been added, just to flesh it out a bit.

**Edit:**
I've found out that the ring modulation was done by a VCS 3, rather than a Moogerfooger, at least in the early days. And the 30Hz carrier wave was supplied by a pre-recorded tape loop.
[BBC Radiophonic Workshop](http://webaudio.prototyping.bbc.co.uk/ring-modulator/)

Also, the digital implementation in SoX is much cleaner that what you get in an analogue implementation with diode distortion. The pre modulation overdrive in the above code goes some way to remedy this, but for a more authentic effect a digital model, like the one created by [Julian Parker](http://recherche.ircam.fr/pub/dafx11/Papers/66_e.pdf), can be used.